# Are these greens 苦木？

Tags: food

My garden neighbor gave me these greens. Is this 苦木？ My neighbor said it is ku3mu4. Did I spell it correctly? What is it called in English?

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: In response to the given answers, here are some entries from my dictionary, but I'm still unsure...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is some sort of "bitter 5433£, but I am not sure. Maybe someone who speaks Chinese better than me can confirm. (?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picrasma_quassioides Is the plant that matches that name but that's a bush/tree, not some type of lettuce.

Comment: Ok, so if that's not what it is, then what is it?

Comment: So, since we're not specialists in Chinese, you might have a better chance of figuring out the correct Chinese word by asking on [chinese.se] to get the name of the plant... What I did was search the name in your question in the Chinese Wikipedia and then find the English version of the page using the sidebar links in Wikipedia.

Comment: The problem is I just just guests the spelling corresponding to the pronunciation. Furthermore, such name could correspond to different plants, and I'm not sure which one this is. I'm sure there must be Chinese users on this site as well, not just on Chinese SE. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there are Chinese users here, but most people aren't. On the other hand, there are a *lot* of Chinese users on [chinese.se], and especially given at least an approximation of what this was called (even if you misheard) they might all stand a chance of recognizing the name. The question is certainly on-topic here if this is where you want it, we're just pointing out something that might help you get an answer.

Comment: It's possible they might be able to identify this over at http://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @catija it is bit a tree with bark, it is a medium-tall plant.

Comment: If you're trying to add details, you can just edit your question. If you're trying to turn this into a plant identification (rather than basing it on the vague description and the approximate Chinese name, which is why I migrated it to Chinese), then like Debbie said, you probably want gardening, and you might want to take a photo of the tree and/or provide more specific details.

Comment: I'm of on vacation at the moment so I cannot add a photo of the plant. Would like to know the name of the plant though.

Comment: The translations from dictionary sometimes will not help. It like that that sheep and goat are both called 羊 in China. And 龙 in China and dragon in the western world are quite (entirely) different.

Answer (score 3):

I don't cook much.

This looks like 油麦菜.

It is a variation of lettuce (Lactuca sativa). From a search on the web (wikipedia), I don't think there is a specific English name for it.

[百度百科](http://baike.baidu.com/view/34825.htm) gives a Latin name "Lactuca sativa var longifoliaf. Lam" for it. The site also says it can be called "莜麦菜", "苦菜" or "生菜" (note: there is also another kind of vegetable called "生菜"). But I've never heard anyone calling it "苦木". And as it is a kind of vegetable, I think it should be unlikely for it to be called "苦木".

Comment: Agreed with 油麦菜, and I never heard of calling it "苦X" either. Maybe we need someone who studies plants to identify this.

Comment: Searching for油麦菜 on Wikipedia gives me rapeseed, but I'm not sure the plant looks the same. I will take a picture of the plant and post back. Thanks.

Comment: Could the plant name be 苦木 in some 浙江 dialect?

Comment: @JackMaddington The Chinese Wikipedia does not have a page for 油麦菜. And I'm not familiar with Zhejiang dialect.

Comment: I'm sure it's 油麦菜. My mother used to plant them, although we call it "麦菜" in Hakka. In China, people usually eat it with sesame paste without cooking.